# Find value for $x$ at a known $y$ on a line

Tags: geometry

So, I have 2 points of a line $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ and I need to find the value of $X$ for a point on the line at a given $Y$.

Any idea how i could do that?

Comment: What is the equation of the line going through the two points ? When this has been answered, you are *almost* done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple when you have an equation (in $x$ and $y$ terms) by putting value of $y$ you can get $x$ and vice versa.

How to get equation?

When you have two points in a straight line  say $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ we can simply make an equation with these two points in $x$ and $y$ terms.
$$y - y_1 = m (x - x_1) $$

Where $$m = \frac{y_2 - y_1} {x_2 - x_1}$$

$m$ is a slope of line.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x = x_1 + \frac{y - y_1}{y_2 - y_1} (x_2 - x_1) 
$$

This will fail if $y_2 = y_1$, but for that situation, either there's no solution or infinitely many, so you couldn't expect a single formula to work.